# React generate select options

Tags: reactjs

It's **SearchForm.js** class, it gets values for select before render using `axios`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class SearchForm extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)

            this.state = {
                position: '',
                area: '',
                period: '1',
                experience: {
                    type: Array,
                    default: () => []
                }
            }

            this.handleExperienceChange = this.handleExperienceChange.bind(this);

        }

        componentDidMount() {
            axios({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'https://example.com/dictionaries/',
                    headers: {
                        'User-Agent': 'React App/1.0 (tatyana.fomina.1986@gmail.com)',
                        'HH-User-Agent': 'React App/1.0 (tatyana.fomina.1986@gmail.com)',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data.experience);
                    this.setState({
                        experience: response.data.experience
                    });
                    console.log(this.experience);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }


        handleExperienceChange(e) {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            });
        }


        render() {
            return ( <
                form className = 'form search-form'
                onSubmit = {
                    this.handleSubmit
                } >
                <
                div className = "form-row" >


                <
                div className = "form-group col-md-2" >
                <
                label htmlFor = "experience" > Experience *< /label> <
                select className = "form-control"
                name = "experience"
                id = "experience"
                onChange = {
                    this.handleExperienceChange
                }
                value = {
                    this.state.experience
                } >

                {
                    this.state.experience.length > 0 &&
                    <
                    option
                    key = {
                        this.state.experience.id
                    }
                    value = {
                        this.state.experience.name
                    } > {
                        this.state.experience.name
                    } <
                    /option> }

                    <
                    /select> < /
                    div >


                    <
                    div className = "form-row" >
                    <
                    div className = "form-group col-md-12 pt-3" >
                    <
                    input id = 'form-button'
                    className = 'btn btn-primary'
                    type = 'submit'
                    placeholder = 'Send' / >
                    <
                    /div> < /
                    div > <
                    /form>
                )
            }
        }

        export {
            SearchForm
        }
```

`console.log(response.data.experience);` shows array with `id` and `name` values
[image]

but `console.log(this.experience);` show `undefined` and `options` stays empty. How to render options with values and set value of the first option as default for this select?

Comment: I think in ```console.log``` you are doing ```this.experience``` instead of ```this.state.experience```

Comment: `console.log(this.state.experience);` shows array of values, but `{
                    this.state.experience.length > 0 &&
                    <
                    option
                    key = {
                        this.state.experience.id
                    }
                    value = {
                        this.state.experience.name
                    } > {
                        this.state.experience.name
                    } <
                    /option> }` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Reagrding the console.log that doesn't show the state correctly, it is probably because setState is asynchronous. Try to put the console.log(this.state.experience) in the setState's callback, and not as it is now, and see what happens.

Regarding the select that doesn't work, it seems that you are using one state variable for both the select options and the value selected by the user...

Last thing: I see only one option tag, and not multiple option tags for all values returned by the axios call.

I hope that this helps.